# How to display Map in hybrid application?

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am developing a hybrid application using IonicFramework. In my case Google Map is displaying on browser, but it is not displaying in Android device.

I have created Google Map key for browser. so it is working fine in browser. but it is not displaying in android.

So, My Question is -

Do i need to create separate google Map key for android as well?

If yes then, how do we integrate google Map code for both platform?

Comment: Welcome to Stacky _the world of Programming_ and please take a look [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

When using the Google maps Javascript API v3 a key is not even mandatory, so getting another one will not solve your problem.

Can you see what error you are getting? (if you got a device plugged in, go to "other tools" > "inspect devices" and check out the console over there.

Are you just getting a gray screen?

Comment: yes i am getting only gray screen. i have also tried with android api key but it is also not working